# Race conditition when using Process RedirectStandardError and RedirectStandardOutput,

Tags: c#, process, outputstream

I find myself in a race condition when subscribing to the output and error stream of `System.Diagnostics.Process`.
Here is a minimal example of what I do:

```
    private string execute(string command, string arguments, int mstimeout)
    {
        string report = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
        Process p = new Process();
        DataReceivedEventHandler ErrorDataReceived = (o, e) => { error.Append(e.Data); };
        DataReceivedEventHandler OutputDataReceived = (o, e) => { output.Append(e.Data); };
        try
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
            p.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;
            p.Start();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit(mstimeout);
            report = output.ToString() + "\n" + error.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            p.OutputDataReceived -= OutputDataReceived;
            p.ErrorDataReceived -= ErrorDataReceived;
        }
        return report;
    }
```

When debugging slowly the behaviour is what I hoped it would be. When running without stops the report ends up empty.

I assume there is a race condition where the underlying streaming objects are disposed before all the output was handled.

Is there something I can do to wait for all the output to be processed?

Comment: You certainly have a race condition on the Output/ErrorDataReceived events, they are raised on a thread-pool thread.  And StringBuilder.Append() is not thread-safe.  Furthermore, the most severe problem, WaitForExit() *only* interlocks and ensure that the streams reach end-of-file when you pass -1 for the timeout.  Using a timeout is just not a good idea when you redirect I/O, make your own with a Timer and Kill() when it trips.

Comment: @HansPassant I see your point. In my usecase I would be uninterested in the report if a timeout occured. The Stringbuilder problem is an issue for me - can I read the Streams later? I heard there is a deadlock when I attempt to use ReadAllLines() on both of them.

Comment: Trying to delay reading the streams will just deadlock the process, it can't make progress when its stdout/stderr buffers are full.  Not sure what you are fretting about, you simply need `lock` in your event handlers so only one of them can append to the builder.

Comment: @HansPassant Later I will need to parse the output and I am unsure If the order of events could change in a way that a later line would be processed before an earlier line. Parsing the output may proove itself to be difficult.

Comment: You need the interlock that WaitForExit() provides so not using a timeout is required.  No other good way to do it, sleeping for a while is not 100% reliable.

Comment: @HansPassant I am rereading what you wrote - did you see that there are two builders? Is that enough to avoid the race?

Comment: Didn't see that, yes.  But of course not the process exit race that WaitForExit() solves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a timeout in certain situations. I needet to `Kill` the `Process` to avoid follow up issues.

```
            if(!p.WaitForExit(mstimeout))
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
```

For good measure I threw in a cleanup in the `finally` part that is likely not needet.

```
        finally
        {
            p.OutputDataReceived -= OutputDataReceived;
            p.ErrorDataReceived -= ErrorDataReceived;
            p.Dispose();
            p = null;
            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, blocking: true);
        }
```

Edit: I deleted the finally part since the comment below seems correct.

Edit: There was a deeper problem where the timeout was hit because of a required input. I ended up invoking a different command that is silent.

---

For future reference - i settled on this now:

```
    private string execute(string command, string arguments, int mstimeout)
    {
        bool timeout = false;
        string report = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
        Process p = new Process();
        DataReceivedEventHandler StoreError = (o, e) => { error.Append(e.Data); };
        DataReceivedEventHandler StoreOutput = (o, e) => { output.Append(e.Data); };
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(command);
            Debug.WriteLine(arguments);
            p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.OutputDataReceived += StoreOutput;
            p.ErrorDataReceived += StoreError;
            p.Start();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            if (!p.WaitForExit(mstimeout))
            {
                p.Kill();
                timeout = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("Process killed");

            }
            else
            {
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            report = output.ToString() + "\n" + error.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(report);
            p.Dispose();
        }
        if (timeout)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout during call: " + command + " " + arguments);
        }
        return report;
    }
```

Comment: The first 4 lines of that `finally` accomplish nothing, the last is *actively harmful*.  The GC will work best when you let it do its work; it pretty much always knows better than you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing you can do anything. I think that Microsoft has completely miss the shot on staring process that you want to get their outputs (output and error). There will always be a problem. At the minimum, it is the race condition you have.
I reported a bug at Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3119134/race-condition-in-process-asynchronous-output-stream-read

Just as reference, this is the code I'm using now (it contains the same race condition problem any implementation running in asynchronous mode would have).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace HQ.Util.General
{
    public class ProcessExecutionWithOutputCapture
    {
        // ************************************************************************
        public class ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult
        {
            public string Error { get; internal set; }

            public string Output { get; internal set; }

            public string ExecutionError
            {
                get
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Error))
                    {
                        return Error;
                    }

                    return Exception?.ToString();
                }
            }

            public bool HasTimeout { get; internal set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Can be cancel through the eventCancel which will cancel the wait (and if set, will kill the process)
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasBeenCanceled { get; internal set; }

            public int ExitCode { get; internal set; }

            public Exception Exception { get; internal set; }

            public bool HasSucceded => !HasTimeout && Exception == null;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private StringBuilder _sbOutput = new StringBuilder();
        private StringBuilder _sbError = new StringBuilder();

        private AutoResetEvent _outputWaitHandle = null;
        private AutoResetEvent _errorWaitHandle = null;

        // Could be usefull when user want to exit to not wait for process to end and kill it (if wanted)
        public EventWaitHandle AdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcess { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcessShouldAlsoKill { get; set; }

        public ProcessWindowStyle ProcessWindowStyle { get; set; } = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        public bool CreateWindow { get; set; } = false;

        public static ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult ExecuteWith(string executablePath, string arguments, int timeout = Timeout.Infinite, ProcessWindowStyle processWindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, bool createWindow = false)
        {
            var p = new ProcessExecutionWithOutputCapture();
            return p.Execute(executablePath, arguments, timeout);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// Only support existing exectuable (no association or dos command which have no executable like 'dir').
        /// But accept full path, partial path or no path where it will use regular system/user path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="executablePath"></param>
        /// <param name="arguments"></param>
        /// <param name="timeout"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult Execute(string executablePath, string arguments = null, int timeout = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult processWithOutputCaptureResult = null;

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // required to redirect output to appropriate (output or error) process stream

                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = CreateWindow;

                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

                _outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                _errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

                bool asyncReadStarted = false;

                try
                {
                    process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOnOutputDataReceived;
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessOnErrorDataReceived;

                    process.Start();

                    // Here there is a race condition. See: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3119134/race-condition-in-process-asynchronous-output-stream-read

                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    asyncReadStarted = true;

                    // See: ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property:
                    //      https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
                    // All 4 next lines should only be called when not using asynchronous read (process.BeginOutputReadLine() and process.BeginErrorReadLine())
                    //_sbOutput.AppendLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    //_sbError.AppendLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
                    //_sbOutput.AppendLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    //_sbError.AppendLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

                    var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[1 + (AdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcess == null ? 0 : 1)];

                    waitHandles[0] = new ProcessWaitHandle(process);
                    if (AdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcess != null)
                    {
                        waitHandles[1] = AdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcess;
                    }

                    bool hasSucceded = false;
                    int waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles, timeout);
                    if (waitResult == 1) // The wait has been interrrupted by an external event
                    {
                        if (IsAdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcessShouldAlsoKill)
                        {
                            process.Kill();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (waitResult == 0) // Process has completed normally, no timeout or external event
                    {
                        // Ensure internal process code has completed like ensure to wait until stdout et stderr had been fully completed
                        hasSucceded = process.WaitForExit(timeout);

                        if (_outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout) && _errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout))
                        {
                            processWithOutputCaptureResult = new ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult();
                            processWithOutputCaptureResult.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
                            processWithOutputCaptureResult.Output = _sbOutput.ToString();
                            processWithOutputCaptureResult.Error = _sbError.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else // Process timeout
                    {
                        processWithOutputCaptureResult = new ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult();
                        processWithOutputCaptureResult.HasTimeout = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex.HResult == -2147467259)
                    {
                        processWithOutputCaptureResult = new ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult();
                        processWithOutputCaptureResult.Exception = new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + executablePath, ex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        processWithOutputCaptureResult = new ProcessWithOutputCaptureResult();
                        processWithOutputCaptureResult.Exception = ex;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (asyncReadStarted)
                    {
                        process.CancelOutputRead();
                        process.CancelErrorRead();
                    }

                    process.OutputDataReceived -= ProcessOnOutputDataReceived;
                    process.ErrorDataReceived -= ProcessOnOutputDataReceived;

                    _outputWaitHandle.Close();
                    _outputWaitHandle.Dispose();

                    _errorWaitHandle.Close();
                    _errorWaitHandle.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return processWithOutputCaptureResult;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void ProcessOnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                _outputWaitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                _sbOutput.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void ProcessOnErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data == null)
            {
                _errorWaitHandle.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                _sbError.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
    }
}
```

Usage (as an application that forward the execution):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using HQ.Util.General;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExecutionForwarder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Console.WriteLine($"App: {Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Executing from folder: {Environment.CurrentDirectory}");
            Console.WriteLine($"at: {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"With args: [{string.Join(" ", args.Skip(1))}]");

            if (args.Length == 1 && args[0].ToLower().StartsWith("-delay:"))
            {
                int millisec;
                if (Int32.TryParse(args[0].Substring(args[0].IndexOf(":") + 1), out millisec))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sleeping for {millisec} milliseconds and will exit.");
                    Thread.Sleep(millisec);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error while trying to read the delay.");
                    Environment.ExitCode = -99;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (args.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine($"Can't forward execution. There is no argument (executable) provided.");
                    Environment.ExitCode = -99;
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = ProcessExecutionWithOutputCapture.ExecuteWith(args[0], string.Join(" ", args.Skip(1)));

                    Console.Write(result.Output);
                    Console.Error.Write(result.Error);

                    Environment.ExitCode = result.ExitCode;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Done in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} millisecs");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually works if you combine two wait statements. First wait for with a timeout. If the timeout hits just kill it. if the timeout is not hit wait without timeout. waiting without timeout has the side effect that you wait for the streams. But I think I see what you mean since the implementation would rely on side effects of tha call.

Comment: @Johannes, The problem is double. 1- you can mix asynchronous with synchronous (which is kind of normal due to race that it would incurs). 2 - Knowing that you cannot mix synchronous with asynchronous means that you can only rely on one mode. Synchronous is limited by it size. If you need large buffer you need to rely on asynchronous mode. But to prevent race condition, the stream should be set in asynchronous mode before the process is started which it is impossible in the current interface Process/ProcessStartInfo is currently implemented.

Comment: I have an implementation that works fine. I will publish it (in few minutes) but it still has the same race condition issue for which I reported a bug.

Comment: I think my class should work for you. If you want to kill your process prematurely then set "IsAdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcessShouldAlsoKill " to true and set "AdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcess " appropriately. Then raise the EventHandle set in "AdditionalConditionToStopWaitingProcess" to kill the process prematurely.

Comment: @EricOuellet What happened with the Connect issue? The link is dead.

Comment: @SeanHall, Sorry I don't remember but there is a lot of chance that it was close with an "Impossible to reproduce" which it appears insane to me but... Like my boss always says: "That's life". Sorry. I do not have a better answer.